# Htaccess 301 rewrite rule with conditions is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What am I doing wrong with this one.

I just want to 301 anything form www.example.com/folder/XXXanythinghereXXX/ to the frontpage http://www.example.com

RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're putting that rule in an htaccess file, you'll need to remove the leading slash. Starting from Apache version 2, the leading slash (or "prefix") is removed before the regex is matched against the URI.

So try:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Or you could use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/ http://www.example.com/
```